# Style between 2 classes

Tags: css, class, between

I have HTML code like

```
<table .. class="atree" .. />
<table><td>a</td></table>
<table><td>b</td></table>
<table><td>c</td></table>
<table><td>d</td></table>
<table... class="btree" .. />
<table><td>e</td></table>
<table><td>f</td></table>
<table><td>g</td></table>
```

Now I want to apply a style for all tds between the two classes "atree" und "btree", e.g. a specific background color. Let's say the expected result is a red background for "a", "b", "c" and "d" only. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to work with the ['next siblings' selector `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors), but that would keep your style going, even after your 'stop' class. There also is a [`:not()` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not), but that does only allow simple selectors, so no `~` inside there. The only solution I see is to counter the styling, by overwriting each property:

A simple example:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li class='start'>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li class='stop'>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
<ul>
```

css:

```
.start, .start ~ li {
    color: green;
}
// note this has to come second, as the specificity is the same as the rule above
li, .stop ~ li, .stop {
    color: red;
    // all your styles need to be countered / reset here
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p0et4yu0/

In javascript this would be fairly easy though. And in real life, I would just add a class to all the elements that I would want to see styled differently (probably even in the server side script), in stead of using some sort of range boundaries.